# underweight girl with the intention of gaining weight and muscle

Tags: weight-gain, bodyweight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

I'm a 20 year old girl and underweight. I'd like to gain more weight so I do not look like a skinny girl. I'm in need of advice how to gain weight as soon as possible. Can you give me suggestions how can I start gaining weight by proper diet, activities like exercises and proper rest?

Note that I've been living a sedentary life for almost 4 years. And experiencing insomnia. Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771) is relevant.

Comment: Betty, it looks like this is a duplicate of the question I linked to. If you have specific details that make your question different, it would be great if you edited your question to include them so we can help.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann can the link you provided be applied to women? thanks.

Comment: Yes it would apply to women. [This other answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6686/does-lifting-more-than-5lbs-really-cause-females-to-bulk/6727#6727) talks a little bit about some myths about heavy lifting for women. Maybe it could help you. If your situation requires more detail, you could edit your question so we can help.